# Lumen Dingo php artisan command error

Tags: lumen, dingo-api

I have installed Lumen, Dingo to test the JWT integration.

On terminal when I try to run unit test case using php artisan command it throws following error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Dingo\Api\Provider\config_path() in /usr/local/var/www/vhosts/storm/vendor/dingo/api/src/Provider/LaravelServiceProvider.php on line 26
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/local/var/www/vhosts/xxx/artisan:0
PHP   2. require() /usr/local/var/www/vhosts/xxx/artisan:18
PHP   3. Laravel\Lumen\Application->register() /usr/local/var/www/vhosts/storm/bootstrap/app.php:84
PHP   4. Illuminate\Container\Container->call() /usr/local/var/www/vhosts/storm/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php:176
PHP   5. Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call() /usr/local/var/www/vhosts/storm/vendor/illuminate/container/Container.php:531
PHP   6. Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod() /usr/local/var/www/vhosts/storm/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php:31
PHP   7. Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}() /usr/local/var/www/vhosts/storm/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php:87
PHP   8. call_user_func_array:{/usr/local/var/www/vhosts/storm/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php:30}() /usr/local/var/www/vhosts/storm/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php:30
PHP   9. Dingo\Api\Provider\LaravelServiceProvider->boot() /usr/local/var/www/vhosts/storm/vendor/illuminate/container/BoundMethod.php:30
```

My `composer.json`:

```
"laravel/lumen-framework": "5.4.*",
"vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
"dingo/api": "1.0.*@dev",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.2",
"lukasoppermann/http-status": "^2.0"
```

Any `php artisan` command is throwing above error.

Answer (score 1):

I can only suspect that you registered the `LaravelServiceProvider` instead of using the `LumenServiceProvider`.
As Lumen *does not* have the helper function `config_path()` you're getting this error.

So according to the [install instructions](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Installation) you should add

`$app->register(Dingo\Api\Provider\LumenServiceProvider::class);`

to your `bootstrap/app.php`.